# Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined in android studio 1.2.1?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

Below are my app dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    // compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
    compile files('src/libs/android_sync_service_library.jar')
    compile files('src/libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project('my module name')
}
```

and my module dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ingosdk')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile files('libs/A2iA.Mobility.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/bugsense-3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/deviceprint-lib-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/espresso-1.1-bundled.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

I am using ActionBarSherlock in my module and appcompat v7 library in my application. In my case both are required. How can I solve the "attribute already defined" issue?

The versions I use in my app:
buildToolsVersion 22.0.1
targetSdkVersion 21

Answer (score 11):

You can't use appcompat-v7 and actionbarsherlock at the same time, just use one of them.